# How to use a dynamic variable-name in JavaScript without eval for a MongoDB update?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In a [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29) application I have an event that should update the database data for changed fields on a form.

So the event handler looks like this:

```
Template.someTemplate.events({'change #someForm' : function(){
    eval("someCollection.update(Session.get(\"currentId\"), {$set: {" + event.target.name + ":event.target.value}});");
}})
```

This works fine, when I use eval. But I doubt it is considered a best practice to use eval like this, or is it?

How would I have to write the MongoDB-update code, to make something like the following work?

```
  Template.someTemplate.events({'change #someForm' : function(){
    var variableName = event.target.name;
    someColletion.update(Session.get("currentId"), {$set: {variableName:event.target.value}});
  }})
```

Or what is the right way, to approach this? (The code above does not work, as for the MongoDB update instruction the *variableName* is not evaluated, so "variableName" is passed instead of its set value.

Note that I want to use this for prototyping, not actually a real application. So security is actually not really an issue. (I am a UX guy, not a software engineer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the object using indexer notation:

```
var param = { $set: {} };
param.$set[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
someCollection.update(Session.get("currentId"), param);
```